# Strange error in Eclipse when viewing xml files

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ibm-rad

I have been getting the following error in IBM RAD when opening an xml file using the XML editor:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Aborted cyclic load attempt for model with id: /Example/src/com/example/resources/example-config.xml
```

Opening the Error Log shows multiple instances of the same error: `Unhandled event loop exception`

Viewing the error has the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.getItem(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder._getToolTip(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder._setToolTipText(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

and the following Session Data:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr11-20120801_118201 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20120801_118201
JIT  - r9_20120608_24176ifx1
GC   - 20120516_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rad.product.v80.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.ibm.rational.rad.product.v80.ide`
```

I also see a record for the original aborted cyclic load attempt error, which has this for the stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.OperationCanceledException: Aborted cyclic load attempt for model with id: /Example/src/com/prototype/resources/example-config.xml
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl$SharedObject.loop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl$SharedObject.waitForLoadAttempt(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getExistingModel(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.model.ModelManagerImpl.getExistingModelForRead(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLTableTreeViewer.setDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.disconnectDesignPage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.dispose(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorStack.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorSashContainer.addEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addToLayout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorAreaHelper.addEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createEditorTab(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditorFromDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.openEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

I am using IBM RAD v 8.0.4.2 which uses Eclipse 3.6.2.

I am hoping that this is a simple configuration issue and that I won't need to do a re-install, since I work in a corporate environment and getting software installed/re-installed is a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spetz

This error looks alike to this Bug in Eclipse

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=332238

It was fixed in Eclipse WTP 3.3.2, but RAD 8.0.x uses WTP 3.2.5. My advise is, if at all possible, upgrade to 8.5 at least, otherwise you will need to contact IBM Support

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/support/contact.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that there was a fix for this besides upgrading, since the version of RAD I am using is the highest that my company allows. I am going to try to do development in straight Eclipse for now. I will give this question another day or two for other answers to show up, otherwise I will mark this as accepted.

Comment: As I said, you can also contact IBM Support to get a fix in your current version